# get the weights of a subclassed model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, subclass, collaborative-filtering

I have been playing around with movielens and collaborative filtering. I used a subclassed model and would like to get the trained embeddings to visualise them in 2d etc. Somehow the weights seem to be empty but I don't know why. Clearly the model is getting better when being trained (if I plot history['loss']). I have no idea why the weights are empty or how to get them If I use a model not as subclass it works fine and I can get the weights. Below is my code

```
class RegressionModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, embedding_size, max_user_id, max_item_id):
        super().__init__()      
        self.user_embedding = Embedding(output_dim=embedding_size,
                                        input_dim=max_user_id + 1,
                                        input_length=1,
                                        name='user_embedding')
        self.item_embedding = Embedding(output_dim=embedding_size,
                                        input_dim=max_item_id + 1,
                                        input_length=1,
                                        name='item_embedding')
        
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dot = Dot(axes=1)
     

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        user_inputs = inputs[0]
        item_inputs = inputs[1]
        
        user_vecs = self.flatten(self.user_embedding(user_inputs))
        item_vecs = self.flatten(self.item_embedding(item_inputs))
        
        y = self.dot([user_vecs, item_vecs])    
        return y
    
    
    
max_user_id = ratings['userId'].max()
max_item_id = ratings['movieId'].max()

thename = 'models/my_model'#cannot save as .h5 as it's a subclassed model
model = RegressionModel(64, max_user_id, max_item_id)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mae')

              
inputs_train = [np.array(ratings_train["userId"]),  np.array(ratings_train["movieId"])]
inputs_test = [np.array(ratings_test["userId"]),  np.array(ratings_test["movieId"])]

model.fit(inputs_train,
                                    np.array(ratings_train["rating"]),
                                    batch_size=64, 
                                    epochs=10, 
                                    validation_split=0.1,
                                    shuffle=True)


#save model
#model.save doesn't work for a subclassed model but save_weights works
def get_model():  
    return RegressionModel(s, max_user_id, max_item_id)

model.save_weights(thename, save_format='tf')


#load the model
model_new = get_model()  
model_new.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mae') 
model_new.load_weights(thename)  

weights = model_new.get_weights()

#this is empty (even without saving and then loading the weights)
weights
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually from tensorflow 2.2 you can save custom models.
You need to specify format,

```py
# Save the model
model.save('path_to_my_model',save_format='tf')

# Recreate the exact same model purely from the file
new_model = keras.models.load_model('path_to_my_model')
```

Try to have a look at [Can't save custom subclassed model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806852/cant-save-custom-subclassed-model)

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't give me an error but the weights are still empty. So when I do this: `weights = model_new.get_weights()`, weights is empty. Nothing is saved. Why?